# Can't fetch data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error :

> Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\islahPos\pos\posDash.php on line 86
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\islahPos\pos\posDash.php:86 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\islahPos\pos\posDash.php on line 86

Please Help me, I am learning PHP

```php
<div class="card-body p-0">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Phone No: </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $select = $pdo->prepare("select * from users order by id desc");
            $select->execute();

            while($row=$select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                echo '
                <tr> 
                    <td>'.$row->id.' </td>
                    <td> '.$row->email.' </td>
                    <td> '.$row->phone.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->join_date.'</td>
                    <td> </td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }  
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


Here is my database connection code


<?php
//initialize variables to hold connection parameters
$username = 'root';
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=register';
$password = '';

try{
    //create an instance of the PDO class with the required parameters
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

    //set pdo error mode to exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //display success message
    //echo "Connected to the register database";

}catch (PDOException $ex){
    //display error message
    echo "Connection failed ".$ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: show your database connection code

Comment: Your $pdo is not declared anywhere. You can try checking your connection to your database first as @Tausif said

Comment: @Tausif thanks, I am giving database connection code

Comment: @MH90 that two code snippets do not match. In your intialization, the connection is held under `$db`, while you use `$pdo` in the other snippet

Comment: @MH90 change $db to $pdo on your connection , because you declared $pdo as connection on your code (where running select query) , or you can just change $pdo to $db on your code (where running select query) . Atleast you need to change at one either on connection or code

Answer (score 1):

simply i added pdo connection above your code and its worked fine , i added these lines before your code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=stack", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

so just check your connection .

Comment: Stop catching exceptions!

Comment: that just added to check if its connected or not , it can be removed if not needed.

Comment: If you have several files that will use the connection to the database. Better to put this code in a php file that you can include afterwards.